# How does Mathematica take a Series expansion at Infinity?

Tags: symbolic, series-expansion

I have a program that requires a series expansion at infinity and at a finite horizon, and I have posted two questions about simplifying these expressions or obtaining the series expansion recently. However, I now realize that I am a little confused about how this expansion even works in Mathematica, since I do not understand some of the test results I have, and I have gone through a few questions such as [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/197969/series-expansion-at-infinity-not-giving-expected-result), [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/156836/regarding-obtaining-a-series-expansion-at-infinity) but I am still a little confused.

Consider the following examples I am obtaining (running Mathematica 11.3 on Windows 10)

```
In:  Series[Sin[x],{x,x0,3}]
Out: Sin[x0]+Cos[x0] (x-x0)-1/2 Sin[x0] (x-x0)^2-1/6 Cos[x0] (x-x0)^3+O[x-x0]^4
```

```
In:  Series[f[x],{x,x0,3}]
Out: f[x0]+(f^\[Prime])[x0] (x-x0)+1/2 (f^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x0] (x-x0)^2+1/6 (f^(3))[x0] (x-x0)^3+O[x-x0]^4
```

These examples I understand. However, at infinity:

```
In:  Series[Sin[x],{x,\[Infinity],3}]
Out: Sin[x+O[1/x]^5]
```

Since sin(x) is bounded, everywhere, I do not understand what this output means.

```
In:  Series[f[x],{x,\[Infinity],3}]
Out: f[x]
```

At infinity, I do not get symbolic series expansions as well. I understand that the regular Taylor series expansion definition around infinity is not meaningful, however, if you look at the second Mathematica notebook in [this](https://centra.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/network/grit/files/amplification-factors/) link (titled *Amplification factors of the superradiant
scattering of a neutral bosonic wave of generic spin off a Kerr BH, obtained by solving the Teukolsky equations*), there is a section of the program that performs a symbolic series expansion at infinity, and I am able to run it and get results as well. So I'm confused about the conditions under which series expansions at infinity return meaningful results, since I think I do not know how to either give the right input, or understand the output from Mathematica. I'm quite new to this.

For reference, the actual code I need help with is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m9b7vnd6wzr4405/Infinity%20Series%20Expansions%20AOS.nb?dl=0) where the `Series` command just runs indefinitely with no results, or errors.

Comment: The sine function has an essential singularity at infinity. Not much `Series` can do about that.

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider an example, where the power expansion at infinity exists, e.g.

```
Normal[Series[(x - 1)/(3 x + 1), {x, x0, 3}]]
```

> $\frac{36 (x-\text{x0})^3}{(3 \text{x0}+1)^4}-\frac{12 (x-\text{x0})^2}{(3 \text{x0}+1)^3}+\frac{4 (x-\text{x0})}{(3 \text{x0}+1)^2}+\frac{\text{x0}-1}{3 \text{x0}+1}$

The above makes no sense at infinity because no arithmetical operation with `Infinity` is defined. The limit of the above at infinity, i.e. `1/3`, is too poor.
I think Mathematica follows usual way of calculus by the change of a variable

```
Normal[Series[(x - 1)/(3 x + 1) /. x -> 1/y, {y, 0, 3}]] /. y -> 1/x
```

> $-\frac{4}{81 x^3}+\frac{4}{27 x^2}-\frac{4}{9 x}+\frac{1}{3}$

The above is identical with the result of

```
Normal[Series[(x - 1)/(3 x + 1), {x, Infinity, 3}]]
```

Comment: What about symbolic expansions, as in the examples I have cited? Because in the code I have, the kernel just resets automatically after running for about an hour.

Comment: How long did you run it for, because for me it just runs indefinitely and I have tested it on another Windows machine as well, running Mathematica 12.3. 
If I set `\[Epsilon] = \[delta] =0` then, I get sensible results (which is a physically well known base case). But for any other value of `\[Epsilon],\[delta]` or if I run it directly as in the code, I do not get the error message you seem to be getting. It runs for an hour, and the kernel resets.

Comment: @newtothis: I deleted my previous comment because I didn't execute `ORDINF = 4;` in your code. Your `eqnaos` is huge and `serinf = Series[{eqni} //. ruleINF, {r, \[Infinity], ORDINF}] // Chop` is running on my comp without any response for a long time. Try to evaluate some parameters in `eqnaos`.

Comment: For any non zero values of the parameters, it still takes too long. The physical ranges of the values are between 0 and 1. So I gave decimal values for `\[Epsilon],\[delta],\[Gamma]1`. That does not seem to help. Simplifying `eqnaos` also takes too long.

Comment: I should also point out that I do a similar series expansion at a symbolic (finite) value of r, and the whole series expansion runs smoothly and gives me an output in around 10-15 mins, without having to evaluate the various parameters in `eqnaos`

Comment: @newtothis: Try to evaluate more parameters, making use of rationals instead of decimals. Start from evaluating all the parameters and decrease `ORDINF` to one.

Comment: So do I set them to fractions? I shall try evaluating the parameters as fractions, and then running the expansion.

Comment: @newtothis: There are syntax errors in your code: in particular ,`hhinf[i]` is not defined and parameter `eps` is omitted..

Comment: `hhinf[i]` is not defined because those are the expansion coefficients I solve for, in a later part of the code, not mentioned in what I attached. I do not understand which parameter `eps` is, since I have defined `\[Epsilon]` in my assumptions and/or while I evaluate it.